# Top -l returning always 0.0 CPU usage when requesting single PID

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, top

On Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) & 10.10 Yosemite I’m unable to get the correct CPU usage for a single process using the `top -l` command for example

```
top -l 1 -ncols 3 -pid <pid>
```

Even though I found a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221555/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-of-a-single-process-on-linux-ubunt) using the ps command I was still wondering why it always returns “0.0”?